# bash check for words in first file not contained in second file

Tags: bash

I have a txt file containing multiple lines of text, for example:

```
This is a
file containing several
lines of text.
```

Now I have another file containing just words, like so:

```
this
contains
containing
text
```

Now I want to output the words which are in file 1, but not in file 2. I have tried the following:

`cat file_1.txt | xargs -n1 | tr -d '[:punct:]' | sort | uniq | comm -i23 - file_2.txt`

`xargs -n1` to put each space separated substring on a newline.

`tr -d '[:punct:]` to remove punctuations

`sort` and `uniq` to make a sorted file to use with `comm` which is used with the `-i` flag to make it case insensitive.

But somehow this doesn't work. I've looked around online and found similar questions, however, I wasn't able to figure out what I was doing wrong. Most answers to those questions were working with 2 files which were already sorted, stripped of newlines, spaces, and punctuation while my file_1 may contain any of those at the start.

Desired output:

```
is
a
file
several
lines
of
```

Comment: What version of `comm` are you using? Mine doesn't support `-i` and expects both input files to be sorted.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus I added the desired output, hope that helps

Comment: @choroba I don't know how to find out the version. When I do `man comm` it has the date January 26, 2005 at the bottom.

Comment: `comm --version` could tell you more.

Comment: @choroba, I tried that:
    `comm --version
    comm: illegal option -- -
    usage: comm [-123i] file1 file2`

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Mac OS X @choroba

Answer (score 0):

I would try something more direct:

```
for A in `cat file1 | tr -d '[:punct:]'`; do grep -wq $A file2 || echo $A; done
```

flags used for grep: q for quiet (don't need output), w for word match

Comment: Wouldn't you still be troubled by punctuation?

Comment: you're right, punctuation removal is probably necessary as you mention it, I fix the proposition

Answer (score 0):

One in awk:

```
$ awk -F"[^A-Za-z]+" '          # anything but a letter is a field delimiter
NR==FNR {                       # process the word list
    a[tolower($0)]
    next
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)          # loop all fields
        if(!(tolower($i) in a)) # if word was not in the word list
            print $i            # print it. duplicates are printed also.
}' another_file txt_file
```

Output:

```
is
a
file
several
lines
of
```

`grep`:

```
$ grep -vwi -f another_file <(cat txt_file | tr -s -c '[a-zA-Z]' '\n')
is
a
file
several
lines
of
```

Answer (score 0):

**`paste`** + **`grep`** approach:

```
grep -Eiv "($(paste -sd'|' <file2.txt))" <(grep -wo '\w*' file1.txt)
```

The output:

```
is
a
file
several
lines
of
```

Answer (score 0):

This pipeline will take the original file, replace spaces with newlines, convert to lowercase, then use grep to filter (`-v`) full words (`-w`) case insensitive (`-i`) using the lines in the given file (`-f file2`):

```
cat file1 | tr ' ' '\n' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep -vwif file2
```